# Query double WITH Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I would like to use with statement twice.

```
WITH userChild AS
(
    WITH deptChild AS
    (
    SELECT dept_no, parent_dept_no, name
    FROM [dbo].[tb_dept] D WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE parent_dept_no = 2
     AND D.company_no = 1

      UNION ALL
      SELECT D.dept_no, D.parent_dept_no, D.name
      FROM [dbo].[tb_dept] D  WITH(NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN deptChild  
   ON D.parent_dept_no = deptChild.dept_no
   WHERE D.company_no = 1
   )
   SELECT user_no
   FROM [dbo].[tb_dept_user] WITH(ROWLOCK)
   WHERE dept_no IN (SELECT dept_no FROM deptChild)
)
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tb_user] U WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE user_no IN (SELECT user_no FROM userChild)
```

This is my code for it. The inside `WITH` statement selects the `user_no` from all `depts` found in `deptChild`. The tb_user table doesn't have a `dept_no` column. So with all the `user_no` found from the `deptChild`, I would like to select all column of that `user_no` from `tb_user` tables. How should I do this?

Comment: The code is clearly SQL Server so I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do this.  Just chain the CTEs:

```
WITH deptChild AS (
      SELECT dept_no, parent_dept_no, name
      FROM [dbo].[tb_dept] D
      WHERE parent_dept_no = 2 AND D.company_no = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT D.dept_no, D.parent_dept_no, D.name
      FROM [dbo].[tb_dept] D INNER JOIN
           deptChild  
           ON D.parent_dept_no = deptChild.dept_no
      WHERE D.company_no = 1
    ),
    userChild as (
     SELECT user_no
     FROM [dbo].[tb_dept_user] 
     WHERE dept_no IN (SELECT dept_no FROM deptChild)
    )
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tb_user] U
WHERE user_no IN (SELECT user_no FROM userChild);
```

Also note that I removed the `WITH (NOLOCK)`.  You should not use such hints unless you are very, very aware of what you are doing.

Comment: To add to Gordon's closing statement, Aaron Bertrand did a great little article on this: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)